# How to change the position of the last flyout (dynamic) with Jquery in a series of dynamic divs in a gallery view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Interesting situation here. One I am bit stumped by. We have a dynamic horizontal gallery list on this page and one of the options is an actions menu that pops out when a gear icon is clicked (image below). However the very last item's popup is towards the edge of the screen and not readable really (edge is cut off, and links are breaking to the second line ). I wanted to select the last div and change the position of the flyout if it is the last however the menu is dynamic and it's positioned with JS already (other screen shot attached). Hope this is enough info. Code snippet below. This menu [image]also shares with a table view. Thank you

[image]

[image]

```
    $galleryCont.on('mouseover','.galleryItem',function(e){
    $(this).find('.orderActionsLink').show();

    }).on('mouseout','.galleryItem',function(e){
                $(this).find('.orderActionsLink').hide();
    });

        //Hides Actions Menu on scroll
           $galleryCont.scroll(function() {
           $('.actionsTableCont').hide();
     });
```

Comment: You can always apply `transform: translateX(-100%)` to the menu when it's of the last column. It will shift it to the left by by its width

Answer (score 1):

I would get the position of the element using jquery's `position()` and then get it's width with jquery's `width()`.

From these values you can calculate if the element's right edge is off the page (more than the viewport width). If yes, you could reposition the div to be to the left of the gear icon instead of the right.

This is similar to how tooltip libraries are smart enough to show the tooltip left, right, top, or bottom depending on the element's proximity to the viewport edge.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not having much luck so far, but I'll keep trying.

Comment: Another idea is to add a class to the last box and then use css to position that menu to the left instead of the right.